# SpriteKit: Could not find an overload for 'runAction' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

The code generates the following error:

If we empty out the `runBlock`, it compiles fine, so it suggests there is something wrong with the `runBlock`. The error is so cryptic, and we cannot figure out the problem.

Any ideas?

```
        func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact!) {
            let nodeB = contact.bodyB.node?

            nodeB?.runAction(
                    SKAction.sequence([
                        SKAction.runBlock {
                            nodeB?.physicsBody?.applyForce( CGVectorMake(0, -2.0) )
                        },
                        SKAction.waitForDuration(0.2)
                    ])
            )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just put the `applyForce` in it's own function and call it inside your `runBlock`:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact!) {
    let nodeB = contact.bodyB.node?

    nodeB?.runAction(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock {
                self.applyTheForce(nodeB!)
            },
            SKAction.waitForDuration(0.2)
            ])
    )
}

func applyTheForce(node:SKNode){
    node.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVectorMake(0, 0))
}
```

Comment: Yah we found this is the only approach that works. Do you know why?

Comment: I think that the kind of method which the physicsbody uses collides somehow with the runBlock. Although I didn't see that problem before.